# X-axis values on a column chart in Plotly incrementing by 0.5 instead of 1

Tags: python, plotly-dash

First question on SO
I'm working on creating visuals for my organization to be embedded into our website when a user logs in.
This specific graph is about the time spent on the system by the user.

I'm using plotly-dash for this
The default view of the graph is to show a line chart of daily time spent and the user has the option to choose monthly, quarterly and yearly view as well. The user has the option to choose any one option from these at a time from radio buttons.

To update the graph when a different radio button is selected I have created the following graph update function:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('time-spent-graph','figure'),
    Input('time-spent-radio','value'))

def update_time_spent_graph(selected_option):
    if selected_option == 'daily':
        graph_data = daily_time_spent
        x_axis_title = 'Date'
        x_values = graph_data['date']
        x_values = x_values.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Format dates as 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        graph_type = 'lines'
    elif selected_option == 'monthly':
        graph_data = monthly_time_spent
        x_axis_title = 'Month'
        x_values = graph_data['month']
        graph_type = 'lines'
    elif selected_option == 'quarterly':
        graph_data = quarterly_time_spent
        x_axis_title = 'Quarter'
        x_values = graph_data['quarter'].astype(str)
        graph_type = 'bar'
    else:
        graph_data = yearly_time_spent
        x_axis_title = 'Year'
        x_values = graph_data['year'].astype(str)
        graph_type = 'bar'
        
    if graph_type == 'lines':
        trace = go.Scatter(
        x=x_values,
        y=graph_data['time'],
        name='Time Spent'
    )
    else:
        trace = go.Bar(
        x=x_values,
        y=graph_data['time'],
        name='Time Spent',
        text=graph_data['time'],  # Use 'time' column for data labels
        textposition='auto',  # Position data labels automatically
        hovertemplate='Time Spent: %{y} minutes'  # Define hover template
    )
    
    return {
        'data':[trace],
        'layout': go.Layout(xaxis = {'title':x_axis_title},
                           yaxis={'title': 'Time (minutes)'},
                           hovermode = 'closest')
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is when I choose Quarterly or Yearly radio button, the x-axis values increment in 0.5 values
Example: For quarterly - x axis values look like 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4
For yearly - x axis values look like 2022, 2022.5, 2023, 2023.5

I don't want to see the x.5 on the x-axis
I was researching online and one suggestion was to convert quartelry and yearly values to str which I've tried in the code pasted above, yet there is no difference observed.

Sorry for the long post, and I appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Converting values to string might do the job, but I strongly suggest you return an actual instance of `plotly.graph_objs.Figure` *and* use [magic underscore notation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#magic-underscore-notation) to ensure the figure is passed to the frontend with all default fallbacks :

```
@app.callback(
    Output('time-spent-graph','figure'),
    Input('time-spent-radio','value'))
def update_time_spent_graph(selected_option):

    # ...

    layout = go.Layout(xaxis_title=x_axis_title,
                       yaxis_title='Time (minutes)',
                       hovermode='closest')

    return go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)
```

That said, you might need to be a bit more explicit so that plotly can properly infer the axis type it should use, you could either :

- add `xaxis_autotypenumbers='strict'` to the layout config, to prevent string values freshly converted from getting converted back to numbers :) see [`autotypenumbers`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-autotypenumbers).
- directly infer the [axis type](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-type) to use in the condition blocks you are using, ie. `xaxis_type = 'date'` for daily option and `xaxis_type = 'category'` for the other options, then add `xaxis_type=xaxis_type` to the layout config.